# Insert Multiple Records at a time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to Insert 10 records in Database at a time,without using any Loops !!
What is another way to do that? I need an Example
Please Help !!!

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

You would use `insert`:

```
insert into t (<column list here>)
    values (<value1 list here>),
           (<value2 list here>),
           . . .
           (<value10 list here>);
```

Or, if the data is in a file, you can use `load data infile`.